# How to copy selective data from one database to another (ORACLE)

Tags: java, oracle

We have a need to find a way to copy certain data from production into our dev regions so that we can debug/fix any issue.
Sometimes single user related data gets impacted. We have to replicate the same scenario in dev and find a solution.
Presently we follow two approaches:-

```
 1. Check the audit history and try to recreate the similar scenario
    in  dev. <50% sucess rate in recreating the exact same scenario.
 2. Restore+Encrypt the "whole" production into dev and then continue
    on  the work. It is an overkill if issue impacts only a single user.
```

So I am trying to find a way to just select a single user data from production and insert it into dev region.

> We just have Java and Oracle. Can't use any external tools. Because we
>   dont have license and cannot download freeware due to security issues.

I tried the follwing:-

1. Write a java code which will query the informaition schema tables to find the relationships between the tables and create select statements like below:-

```
select 'insert into TABLE1(C1,C2,C3,C4) values ('||''''||C1||''''||','||coalesce(to_char(C2),'null')||','||''''||C3||''''||','||coalesce(to_char(C4),'null'));'
from TABLE1 where ID='1006' union all 
select 'insert into TABLE2(C1,C2,C3,C4) values ('||''''||C1||''''||','||coalesce(to_char(C2),'null')||','||''''||C3||''''||','||coalesce(to_char(C4),'null'));'
from TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1ID in ( select ID FROM TABLE1 where ID='1006') union all 
select 'insert into TABLE3(C1,C2,C3,C4) values ('||''''||C1||''''||','||coalesce(to_char(C2),'null')||','||''''||C3||''''||','||coalesce(to_char(C4),'null'));'
from TABLE3 WHERE TABLE2ID in ( select ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1ID in ( select ID FROM TABLE1 where ID='1006'));
```

2. Use this set of selects in production, so that you get a set of insert statements as output.
3. Use the insert statements in dev.

**Problem:-**
The select queries are becoming huge. Around 25 MB in total :(
We cannot even execute that big query in production.

Could you suggest any better approach for this usecase?
Does oracle itself allow selective data exports? Or any other way I should write my java code?

Comment: How about creating another schema and copy over only table / rows needed to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: We will need to copy rows with all the dependent rows. That is making the select statements huge :(

Comment: are you using any orm in your java side?

Comment: No I was not using ORM because I just wanted to generate the sqls through java. But we can use ORM if you can suggest an approach. Just that, we dont want to load the production server with lots of select queries.

Comment: Did you try using DATABASE LINK, here is a reference [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm), you can create a link of prod env at dev environment and then copy relevant data from production to dev environment

Answer (score 5):

We use something like this to move records from one database to another:

`copy from username/password@database1 to username/password@database2 insert target_table using select * from source_table where where_clause_goes_here;`

Comment: Can I add multiple select queries in this command? For all the dependant tables?

Comment: Sorry, but I checked the website https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm
But not sure if the following will work:-
copy from username/password@database1 to username/password@database2 
insert target_table using select * from source_table where where_clause_goes_here
insert target_table1 using select * from source_table1 where where_clause_goes_here
insert target_table2 using select * from source_table2 where where_clause_goes_here;

Comment: Couldn't you do each table as a separate statement?

Comment: Technically I could. But our DBAs will be really upset.

Comment: You need a better DBA. Why would he care if the script has one single command or multiple? Since you have a DBA just ask to have the data moved. The DBA can then decide on a way that suits their mood.

Comment: yep - ask your dba to snapshot the production VM and set it up as an EVAL server for your test.

Comment: @Randy what is EVAL server? Do you mean copy the production DB and restore in a separate environment for testing? I think we can do that.. may be weekly.

Comment: @Hirak - yes a temporary new server for use in evaluation and testing.  it will likely be very difficult or impossible to get the minimum subset of records that recreates a problem - best to have the entire thing.

Comment: I think this is a very practical solution. Is there a way to mask the data? Do you know if DBAs will have any tool for masking?

Comment: @MathiasMagnusson Yeah this is a pain... but you know, all these inter-department dependencies et al!

Answer (score 5):

Use datapump to move data for the tables you need and with the whereclause you want. Straight forward and standard functionality of the database.

Comment: SQL Developer, part of your Oracle Database license, has a GUI for Data Pump, it's very easy to select your objects and apply WHERE clause filters to grab just the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

If both the DBs are Oracle, you can create a DBLINK in your local 
database for the remote DB and Create a job in your local DB that queries 
all the data from remote DB using the DBLINK, and update the tables in your 
local database.
Or there are plenty of data migration API are availabe you can give a try to one of them.

Below are the some link,have a look in to them,may be it will solve your problem

http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/

http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java.html

http://migrate4j.sourceforge.net/

http://flywaydb.org/ --- its better to use

http://www.operatornew.com/2012/11/automatic-db-migration-for-java-web.html

Comment: Production cannot be linked to lower environments through DBLINK. And as far as I know, you cannot mask data through DBLINK. You dont want to expose produciton data without masking now... would you?